# css how to make an elements margin-bottom go to bottom of its container

Tags: html, css

I need to have an element have a `margin-bottom` equal to `100%` of its container.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/5hz4g/3/

I would like the `padding / margin` (padding was used so colors could illustrate) to make the `to-bottom` div be as tall as the container and push everything to the right.

If i have something like that the margin of `to-bottom` goes to the bottom of the page. I would like it to go to the bottom of the `container`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried vertical-align:bottom;?

Comment: sorry, but I couldn't understand what `margin-bottom: 100%`! is what you want to fix the `to-bottom` div always at the bottom of the container? also, please put your code in >> http://jsfiddle.net/ <<

Comment: can you give us some more information, like height of the container , is there any content in it as well before or after your #to-bottom ?

Comment: @SULTAN http://jsfiddle.net/5hz4g/1/ i used padding so the colors could illustrate my point.

Comment: "and push everything to the right" << what other things? and what do you mean by pushing to right.

Comment: @SULTAN if you look at the example you can see that "Other stuff here" is being pushed to the right.

Comment: So you want the other staff to be to the right, but (top or bottom)?

Comment: is this what you want? >> http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/5hz4g/2/

Comment: @SULTAN no i want it the exact same as i had before except that the green div is only as tall as the red one. I cant set it to 50px because the height will be dynamic and change

Comment: @GCyrillus the height of the container will be dynamic - check out the edit to the post.

Comment: Sorry but what I understand now is you want two divs `[greenDiv][redDiv]` next to each other, with the same height? is that right?

Comment: and in the `[greenDiv]` you want its content to be on the bottom...

Comment: @SULTAN no the content of the green div will be on the top - like i showed in the example. I just want the green div to be the same height as the red one.

Comment: Please check this and let me know... http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/5hz4g/5/

Comment: glad I could help :)) I will update my answer and you may accept it if you wish.

Comment: @GCyrillus, based on the OP comments: "the content of the green div will be on the top".. he just wanted the two divs to be with the same height so he was trying to accomplish that by trying the `margin-bottom`

Comment: okay, what was that fuss about to-bottom 100%, really unclear way to ask something simple :) as 2 col same height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="to-bottom">
        this is always @ bottom of parent div
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #eee;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.to-bottom{
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**See Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/3jPMk/**

**UPDATE:** *After discussion with the OP, his need was to have two divs next to each other with the same height*

*based on that, my answer is beeing update to the following:*

### **[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/5hz4g/5/)**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="greenBox">
        This is GREEN Box
    </div>
    <div class="redBox">
        This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. This is RED Box.. 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;    
}
.greenBox{
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #a9e8a2;
    display: table-cell;
}
.redBox{
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #ec6446;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry it was unclear before.